# Unable to determine if any bash script is still running without modifying or renaming script

Tags: bash, shell-script

We come across various customer bash scripts that could be doing anything. I don't care what it does but I need a simple way of determining whether the .sh script has finished or if it's still doing something which could be many minutes. The scripts cannot be modified, renamed or moved. We also need to be able to output anything that the script outputs to stdout; so we can't > null either.

I've found various posts about this but no solution is working. I tried creating a simple `test.sh` script that just contains echo "Hello World" and a for do loop so that the script never stops but I cannot find a working solution that tells me yes, the script is still running. Solution needs to be as simple as possible, such as a one liner. I tried something simple like

```
if $? -eq 0 then script finished successfully
```

but `$?` will always return some number but this won't tell you if it's finished running or not.

```
pgrep -l ./test.sh or pgrep -x ./test.sh
```

was posted as a solution for others but this doesn't work for me. It just goes to the command prompt and not printing any output.

The `test.sh` script I created doesn't show up as a process either. Seems to just show `-bash` and that's it. Need this working for Unix/Linux.

What else can I do to determine that a script is still running and hasn't returned to the command prompt?

UPDATE: Maybe this explains my problem better. When you open an ssh terminal session and run a script that may take 2 mins or 20 mins to finish you know it's done when you see the command prompt again. So you don't type the next command until you see the prompt. Easy.

But how can you do the same thing without any human assistance? How can I tell Linux to

1. From a windows pc, open an SSH session to a remote pc and
2. run `./script.sh` and
3. run the command `whoami` ONLY when 2) has completed successfully?

All this without writing and executing a separate script, or making changes to the script in step 2)? In other words only from a command prompt. So you can still use multiple linux commands separated by `;` or if possible, write a script on the command line without saving it and then executing this command (pressing ENTER)? It's kind of hard to explain this but hopefully this makes more sense now.

Comment: Try `pgrep -fa test.sh`. Use `-u` or `-U` to limit to certain users. Use `-x` to make it more specific.

Comment: Thanks, but it seems that any use of pgrep results in no output. Doing this in Ubuntu now and it just goes back to the prompt and I checked the processes manually and there is no test.sh process or name found. If I just run ./test.sh I can see it's printing Hello World inifinitely and I just CTRL-C to abort. So I know the script runs infinitely as intended. I just cannot get any command to determine this.

Comment: Output will look like this: `18291 /bin/bash ./test.sh`. The `-f` option is essential.

Comment: Yes but again there is no output at all. I'm running pgrep -fa test.sh and it shows nothing. I tried pgrep -n to show the newest process started and it does show a PID. When I check this pid it with ps -ef shows "[kworker/u513:0-events_unbound]" for the command name while I have the script running infinitely in another terminal session.

Comment: `pgrep -na` may give some indication what this process is. Also try `pgrep -fa bash`.

Comment: Thanks, but this outputs nothing and just goes back to the prompt. I don't think we can use pgrep as a solution because it'll never match the script name. test.sh does not show up as a process or command name anywhere. All you see is [kworker/u513:0-events_unbound]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115347/discussion-between-lasse-kliemann-and-yorkman).

Comment: It depends how you initiate the job. For example, `bash < test.sh` makes the current (terminal) bash send the script text to a sub-shell, which does not even know the name of the script it is running. A devious script could even relaunch itself, disown that copy, and exit, making itself anonymous and parented by process 1. You could also do that within `at` or `cron`, so it does not belong to a terminal either.

Comment: Ok, so if we ssh to a system (step #1) and (#2) run: bash < test.sh and next step we want to run some command or other script, what command wouldd we need to enter to determine that bash < test.sh is finished running before proceeding to the next step and disconnecting the ssh session?

Comment: I can't think of any method which I couldn't easily circumvent in some way from inside test.sh. And, because that script can launch further background jobs, and disown them, the script can "finish running" and still leave any number of children running for ever. Or it can set up an `at` job to run itself again, after you have checked it has "finished".

Comment: test.sh is only an example I used for testing purposes. It is actually a script that runs on a production system so we cannot touch it in any way. We cannot rename it, move it or anything like that. All that we can do is run commands. It'd be nice if echo $? would always be null until the script has finished because then we could simply have the next step wait for an exit code of 0 or some other number because we could just add an if $? -eq 0 then go run the next command. But I think it's always going to return 0 or some other number depending on if there is an error even while script runs.

Comment: No. `$?` returns the *completion* status of the last command run by *this shell*. If the command is still running, exactly where are you running `echo $?`? Why would you expect a different shell to know the status of a command started by another shell in a different session? Why would a command have a completion status if it has not yet completed?

Comment: Like you said, if script hasn't finished then echo $? will return status of an earlier command or script, not the currently running script that may or may not have finished. Another words with echo $? we never know for which command or script we're getting a return code for. If Step #1 is ssh to machine, #2 is run test.sh script and #3 is echo $? and #2 is still running then we are getting exit code for #1 aren't we? Because step #1 is the last command/script to have completed.

Comment: No again. If you ran test.sh and it has not completed, you don't have a command prompt, so you CANNOT RUN echo $? at that point, in that shell. Please show a transcript of an actual session so we can understand precisely what you are doing, and know why it is not working.

Comment: If you're on Linux, `find /proc/*/fd -lname '*/script.sh' 2>/dev/null` will tell you any process which is *still* running `script.sh`. (If `script.sh` had a line like `exec foo`, the same process which was running `script.sh` is now running `foo`, whatever that it).

Comment: What you state in the chatroom (but not here) is that every step in your RunBook is run on another machine via ssh. Also that you can't open another ssh session there to check progress. So exactly where are you running these pgrep things -- on the local machine?

Comment: Thanks Uncle Billy. It looks like this works though I'm not sure what exactly it's telling me when it returns: /proc/82403/fd/254 I'm guessing 82403 is the PID but not sure what 254 means. Is there a way to perhaps wrap cmds when starting script.sh? This way when the script does finish and it goes to the prompt it can continue with any other commands? I need to know, after running any script, when can I enter the next command without guessing when the script might've finished running. Maybe with tee? So logic is: 1) run script.sh then wait until it's finished and run next cmd

Comment: Paul: Think of it as a process (kind of a master script) that you're building. So you are creating multiple steps which are basically command executions. So first step might be 1) ssh to a remote machine from any other machine and 2) run a script and 3) run a command ONLY when the script in step 2) has completed. But of course there's no command prompt for step 3) until step 2) is done. Right now all I can do is try to guess that the script might run for 4 mins before I get a command prompt then run next command. But it might run for 12 mins or who knows how long.